# Smallest sigma-algebra on which difference of measurable functions is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let's assume that $f,g$ are $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ measurable. Then we know by the usual theorem that $f-g$ is also $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ measurable. But what's the smallest sigma-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on which the $f-g$ is measurable?

Motivation: This question comes from reading on book an example of a random variable $Y_n:=X_{2n}-X_{2n-1}$. The author states that $Y_n$ is $\sigma(X_{2n},X_{2n-1}),\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ measurable. And I wondered why...

Also have another question, related to this. Is $(f-g)^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)) \subset \sigma\{f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))\cup g^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))\}$?

Comment: If the question is: "How to express the sigma-algebra $\sigma(f-g)$ generated by $f-g$ in terms of $\sigma(f)$ and $\sigma(g)$?", then the answer is obviously: "That depends", as studying the simplest examples one can think about, shows.

Comment: Did you realize your question would be answered by an answer to "Let $f$ be a function. What is the smallest sigma algebra for which $f$ is measurable?"

Comment: The "motivation" you added is quite unrelated to the rest of the question. To answer the "motivation" part, simply note that $\sigma(g(X))\subseteq\sigma(X)$ for every measurable function $g$, and apply this to $X=(X_{2n},X_{2n-1})$ and $g(x,x')=x-x'$.

Comment: @Hurkyl I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say... sorry

Comment: @Did thanks for the help. ;)

Comment: To paraphrase a recent meta post: *Until now, this question has 6 upvotes, but I'm having a hard time understanding the reasons why.*

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends. For instance, consider $f,g : (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$, $f(x) = x+1$, and $g(x) = x$. $f(x) - g(x)=1$, which is measurable with respect to any $\sigma$-algebra, in particular, you can take $F = \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Aaron, but in your example I don't think we have $ f , g:(\mathbb{R}, (f-g)^{-1}(\mathcal{B}))\rightarrow(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}) $

Comment: Aaron, I've edited the question.  ;)

Comment: We don't have $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B})\subset (f-g)^{-1}(\mathcal{B})$ or $g^{-1}(\mathcal{B})\subset (f-g)^{-1}(\mathcal{B})$